# $DEBUG global variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can someone please summarize what/when is `$DEBUG` used. I am unfamiliar with it, and had no luck finding documentation (the [Class Thread documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html) and [Module Signal documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html)).

These are examples that are not clear to me what's going on:

```
p @ivar if $DEBUG
```

and:

```
Signal.trap("USR1") do
  $debug = !$debug
  puts "Debug now: #$debug"
end
```

Comment: 3 seconds of Googling: http://nhw.pl/wp/2006/08/04/debug-variable-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two are totally different. The first is a debugging line executed only if `$DEBUG` is set; `$DEBUG` is set if you pass the command-line argument `-d` to `ruby`.

The second is flipping a `$debug` variable (different case!!), which is specific to the program. When you hit the process with a `SIGUSR1` signal, it will change the debug mode (useful for getting it to print debugging information only sometimes).

Comment: would you please show example of setting it in command line, ty!

Comment: Uh, `ruby -d <script>`. (Or `RUBYOPT=-d ruby`).